# VBA after sort event

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have excel sheet, where I have bunch of data and some excel filter and sort buttons. Is there possibility to detect when sort function was executed and run code after?

I tried worksheet_calculate, but there is issue, that this event is firing not only on sort. Or is here possibility to determine that sort was performed in worksheet_calculate event?

Answer (score 0):

**Control** the sort rather than have Excel try to **detect** the sort.
Instead of allowing the user to manually perform sorts from the Ribbon, provide a button and have the button macro perform the sort and any associated actions afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, i have button for my custom sort, but also there are excel buttons, that allows filters. And this buttons also contains A-Z sort. And i wana to perform some data maintance after this native sorting. Thats why im trying to detect sort event :/

Answer (score 0):

A sort action changes the selection of its filter range. You can capture the sort event quite simply by utilizing the Worksheet_SelectionChange event. You must apply the Application.Intersect method the same way you would for a standard Worksheet_Change event.

The range you are testing against the selection target must be the filter range EXCLUDING the header row.

When you sort one of the columns within the filter range via the header controls, the Target.Value will capture an array including the header row values.

You need two lines of code at this point to help detect the sort action. Please see basic skeleton below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim filterRangeNoHeaders As Range
  Set filterRangeNoHeaders = Range("A2:A11")
  If VarType(Target.Value) <> 8204 Then Exit Sub
  If Target(1, 1) <> "FirstHeaderTitle" Then Exit Sub
  If Not Application.Intersect(filterRangeNoHeaders, Target) _
    Is Nothing Then
    'Code to execute after sort is detected
  End If 
End Sub
```